Why is $dx = r^{n-1} dr dy$ for $x=ry$?
I am a little confused in trying to understand the Jacobian for a certain change of variables.
So, if we have $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we change to spherical coordinates $x = f(r,\theta)$ where $r$ is the length of the vector and $x_1 = r cos\theta_1$, $x_2 = r \sin \theta_1 \cos\theta_2$, $x_3 = r \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos\theta_3$, ..., we have that the Jacobian is given by
$$J_n(r, \theta_1, \dots, \theta_{n-1}) = r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}\theta_1\sin^{n-3}\theta_2\dots\sin\theta_{n-2}$$
(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1621127/948036)
Now, I am trying to understand work that uses the change of variables $x = ry$, where $r$ is the length of the vector, and $y$ is a vector in the unit sphere, that also has $n$ components. Such work (e.g. here, just beneath formula (1)) say that $dx = r^{n-1}drdy$, where $dy$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on the unit sphere (I'm unfamiliar with measure theory). Thus, if I have some probability distribution in terms of $x$ and I re-express it in terms of $(r,y)$, the Jacobian that I have to multiply by is $r^{n-1}$.
I am struggling to understand what happened to all the terms that depend on $\theta$ in the first case, given that these two parametrizations seem so similar. Another example is this work, where they do start explicitly including a factor $f(\theta)$ in their Jacobian (formula 2.1), but they just drop it in one step without mentioning why (from 2.3 to 2.4).
So, the question is, why is the Jacobian for $x=ry$ equal to $r^{n-1}$, and why is it different than the jacobian for the spherical coordinate transform.

All of the terms which depended on $\theta^i$ have been enveloped into the $dy$ term.
Essentially, since $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus 0=\mathbb R\times S^{n-1}$, integrating over $\mathbb R^n$ is the same as integrating over the above cartesian product, with coordinates $(r,y)$, where $y$ determines your space on the sphere.
Basically, if you were just integrating over the surface of a sphere with the angle coordinates $(\theta_1,\dots, \theta_n)$, then this would be same as integrating over the box $[0,\pi]\times [0,2\pi]^{n-2}$ with $dy=\sin^{n-2}\theta_1\cdots \sin\theta_{n-2}d\theta _1\cdots d\theta_n$. Integrating in spherical coordinates is the same as including $r^{n-1}dr$ in this expression, hence for ease of notation you can just write $r^{n-1}drdy$, especially if the function you’re integrating has spherical symmetry (which is pretty much the only reason you want to switch to spherical coordinates in the first place).

Thanks, but I still don't quite understand why $dy=\sin^{n-2}\theta_1\cdots \sin\theta_{n-2}d\theta _1\cdots d\theta_n$. I do understand conceptually that the $\theta^i$ terms are enveloped by $dy$, but I am lacking a more precise mathematical understanding of why this is so.

@dherrera Set $r=1$ then your integrating over a sphere. Why don’t you try and figure out the volume element of a sphere in the $n=3$ setting

Thanks for the pointer. So, what I would need to do is find out what volume in angle space ($d\theta^1 d\theta^2$) corresponds to an area on the sphere ($dy$)? and that should match the term with all the $sin \theta$ and $cos \theta$? I might be able to do it with quite some effort, but if you want to provide some more guidance, that would be appreciated. In particular, I'm not sure how to think about the area element for $dy$

@dherrera I mean just write spherical coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$ and integrate whatever you want over $r=1$.
